# Dealing with antivirus false positives

Tags: antivirus

I'm in the process of releasing my first game on steam. As part of a review process the executable is sent to about 70 virus detection services through https://www.virustotal.com/

One of these called VBA32 reported my executable as malicious (BScope.TrojanSpy.Keylogger), which must be a false positive. I've tried contacting the antivirus company but haven't head back yet.

How would you go about dealing with this?
Is this likely to affect customers trying to install the game?
Are there any best practices for not getting flagged by antivirus?

The game is written in a custom c++ engine using only the win32 libraries.

Comment: Is it code signed with a real Authenticode certificate from DigiCert or similar?  Unsigned apps are more likely to be flagged.

Comment: @Dave S I used visual studio for coding, so unless there is any built in signing there it is unsigned. Any advice on where to get dtarted on codesigning for a beginner?

Comment: you need to buy a cert, then use it to sign - https://www.digicert.com/signing/code-signing-certificates

Comment: Note: signing your EXE and installer will definitely help with some Windows OS, SmartScreen and Defender warnings but it won't remove all chance of AV false positives.